# Redirecting Input in Linux

Tags: linux, redirect, terminal

I have a 2 files: test and input1. 
The following is my "test" file:

```
echo $1 $2
```

Changing the output works as when I write in the terminal:

```
./test foo bar > input1
```

the string "foo bar" is written to input1.
Yet, when I write in the terminal:

```
./test < input1
```

all that is printed in the terminal is a skipped line.

Any ideas why "foo bar" is not getting printed to the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

It is because **test** doesn't echo **standard input**, it echoes the **command arguments**.

The values `$1` and `$2` represent the first and second arguments on the command line and they are what test echoes.

The less-than ("<") notation redirects standard input (by default, the console in an interactive shell) and you are redirecting standard input sent to **test** to come from **input1**, but **test** doesn't even look at standard input, it only looks at the command line arguments.

To get the shell to behave more like you expect, you have to take the content of **input1** and put it in the command arguments that are passed to **test**.

Perhaps this is what you intended:

```
./test $(cat input1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you should do:

```
./test `cat input1`
```

This way, the content of input1 will be passed to the command as arguments, not as standard input.

Suppose the content of input1 is:

```
a b c
```

It would be the same as calling your script as this:

```
./test a b c
```

Inside your script, you will receive a, b and c as variables:

```
$# = 3
$1 = 'a'
$2 = 'b'
$3 = 'c'
```

How ever, imagine that you want to use input1 as standard input inside your script. So you would call your script like this:

```
./test < input1
```

and inside your script, suppose you want to pass the content of input1 to `grep`. You would do something like this:

```
grep b <1
```

This would search for the string 'b' in the input1 file.

To see more examples, take a look at this page:
http://www.mathinfo.u-picardie.fr/asch/f/MeCS/courseware/users/help/general/unix/redirection.html

Comment: So what would be an example of a script that would print input redirected by the < operator to the screen?

Comment: To clarify - I'm experimenting with redirects in Linux, and I want to write a simple script that would appropriately take input from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Input may be redirected in bash as follows (I am still new to Linux):

`cat <& 0`

Here, `0`, represents `Console Input` while, `1`, would represent `Console Output` and, `2` represents `Console Error Output`.